# PDFsharp With Chinese Characters and the Microsoft YaHei font Not Supported?

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I'm trying to create a PDF document in different languages but I'm having trouble with Chinese, Japanese, and Indian characters.

I've tried this:

```
XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Automatic);
var font = new XFont("微软雅黑", 9, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
```

but it just throws an exception

> InvalidOperationException: Font has no usable platform or encoding ID. It cannot be used with PDFsharp

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong with that...

I've also tried the `gfx.MUH=PdfFontEncoding.Unicode;` approach but that again doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.
ive also tried `var font = new XFont("Arial Unicode MS", 9, XFontStyle.Regular);` which also doesn't work
My main question is how can I write Chinese characters with PDFsharp the font I know is wrong and will use a proper font for the real thing

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEZwE.png) [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PC9L.png)

Comment: In your code snippet you use a method that is obsolete. Are you using PDFsharp 1.50 or 1.51? Or a stone-old version? Or maybe a port of PDFsharp?

Comment: installed 1.50.5147 and it tells me that the PdfFontEmbedding.Automatic is obsolete but ive seen others use this and thought i needed it

Comment: @Luka1 others may not care about possible bugs. The *library itself* tells you this is obsolete - this means no bugs will be fixed and the code may be deleted at any point

Comment: @Luka1 the error clearly complains about *this particular* font. What font is this, where did you find it? In 2020 all fonts work with Unicode, the question is whether they contain the proper glyphs for one Unicode range or another. The fonts used to display *this* page obviously support all ranges.

Comment: If you inspect this page to see what fonts are used to render the Chinese characters you posted, you'll see they're nothing special. The code section specifies monospaced fonts like Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console etc. The text just Arial, Helvetica etc. Have you tried creating the page with one of the common fonts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746920/pdfsharp-with-chinese-characters i found the font here and my main question is how can i write Chinese characters with PDFsharp?

Comment: @Luka1 If PDFsharp tells you that a font is not supported then try a different font. I don't see a font file on that linked question, I only see a font name. There may be different fonts with that name and some may work while others don't.

Comment: @JesuisMonica-Ihibernate its not about the font i know the font is wrong but var font = new XFont("Arial Unicode MS", 9, XFontStyle.Regular); this doesnt work as well

Comment: On my machine I see that `DengXian Regular` and `SimSun-ExtB Regular` are `.ttf` files, all others are `.ttc`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i dont have the gfx.MFEH = PdfFontEmbedding.Automatic; error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'XGraphics' does not contain a definition for 'MFEH' and no accessible extension method 'MFEH' accepting a first argument of type 'XGraphics' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Luka1 wrong link, the correct one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791080/migradoc-pdfsharp-throwing-exceptions-with-chinese-yahei-font

Answer (score 1):

The GDI build of PDFsharp supports TrueType fonts, but no PostScript fonts.

The WPF build should also work with PostScript fonts.

If you get the error message that a font is not supported then either try a different build of PDFsharp or try a different font.

Comment: ive only seen this "微软雅黑" font used to supposedly support Chinese characters but it hast worked at all and i think this method will not work as for the different build of PDFsharp do you know any that absolutely work?

Comment: This isn't a matter of TrueType vs Postscript as this page shows - browsers don't need Postrcript fonts to render this page.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It does matter because PDFsharp must be able to dissect the font file. If the font has an unsupported format then the font cannot be used - even if there is a browser that supports the font.

Comment: @JesuisMonica-Ihibernate we're talking about plain-old Arial and Consolas here, TrueType fonts available in all Windows versions

Comment: @JesuisMonica-Ihibernate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746920/pdfsharp-with-chinese-characters this is where i found the font but the font i don't really care about its just to display Chinese characters but no matter what i tried i kept gfetting the result i added to the question

Comment: @Luka1 have you tried with just *Arial*? Windows already comes with fonts that can cover most Unicode ranges, including Chinese

Comment: @Luka1 worst case, just post the Chinese text in Word or any other text editor you like and check which of the built-in fonts renders this correctly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos im using var font = new XFont("Arial Unicode MS", 9, XFontStyle.Regular); currently and i cant cange the system currently easily to word :(

Comment: @JesuisMonica-Ihibernate looks like you already answered [an exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791080/migradoc-pdfsharp-throwing-exceptions-with-chinese-yahei-font). The OP is trying to use the Microsoft YaHei font, without actually mentioning it by name.